# Set a cross in QImage at the position, where mousepressed

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.6, qt4.7

I have a graph shown in a QImage and want to set a cross (+) in yellow colour for measurement, if right mouse button is pressed.

```
        void foo::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
        {
         if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
            QPoint pos = event->pos();
            int x = pos.x();
           int y = pos.y();
          QLine line(x-5,y,x+5,y);
          QLine line(x,y-5,x,y+5);
          QPainter painter(&my_image);
          painter.setPen( Qt::red );
          painter.setBrush( Qt::yellow );
/*
QPainter::begin: Cannot paint on an image with the QImage::Format_Indexed8 format
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
*/


              painter.drawLine(line); //no effect 

         }
        }
```

if I do it in Paintevent(...), I destroy the original pic. how can I do it.

additional Information:
the imag is indexed.

```
 my_image.setColorCount(33);
    for(int i = 0;i<33;i++)
    {
        my_image.setColor(i,qRgb((unsigned char)palette[i*3], (unsigned char)palette[i*3+1], (unsigned char)palette[i*3+2]));
    }
```

my_imag has a black-Background and I  want to draw a cross in white color --> (this is the index 32)

int color = 32;//_index_value_of_cross_color;

```
      for (int ix=x-5;ix<x+5;ix++) {
           my_image.setPixel(ix,y,color);
      }

      for (int iy=y-5;iy<y+5;iy++) {
           my_imag.setPixel(x,iy,color);
      }
```

but I see no effect !

Comment: How are you drawing the lines? You should be using a QPainter initialised to use the QImage as a paint device.

Comment: I draw the Lines using QPainter see changes in code .

Comment: Do you use a `QGraphicsView` for displaying the image?

Comment: if I click I get the Error: 
 
QPainter::begin: Cannot paint on an image with the QImage::Format_Indexed8 format

QPainter::begin: Cannot paint on an image with the QImage::Format_Indexed8 format
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, you cannot paint on a QImage with Format_Indexed8.

From the QImage docs:

[**Warning**: Painting on a QImage with the format QImage::Format_Indexed8 is not supported.](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qimage.html)

Choose a different format like QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied and things should work.

Comment: QImage::Format_ARGB32 does not help

Comment: QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied is the enum, not the non-premultiplied one.

Answer (score 1):

Another quick and dirty alternative is to simply set the values in the image data.

You will have to do a little more work - because there is no line command, see [setpixel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html#setPixel)

```
int x = pos.x();
int y = pos.y();
int color = _index_value_of_cross_color;

for (int ix=x-5;ix<x+5;ix++) {
     my_image.setPixel(ix,y,color);
}

for (int iy=y-5;iy<y+5;iy++) {
     my_image.setPixel(x,iy,color);
}
```

Comment: If the image is indexed then you need to set the index of whichever color you want the cross - just a number 0-255

Comment: the image is indexed

my_image.setColorCount(33);
for(int i = 0;i<33;i++)
    my_image.setColor(i,qRgb(r[i], g[i], b[i]));
    

and I set the color to 32 (white). background is black. But I see no effect.